# Transpose a 150x3000 field CSV file

Tags: csv

I'm looking for a software (not an online tool) that can transpose large CSV files. I found [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16230/speadsheet-software-that-can-handle-thousands-of-columns) answer, but the proposed tool can't handle my file. I also heard about EmEditor, which can handle large files and has CSV capabilities, but at least I couldn't find the "Transpose" feature.

My OS is Windows, but I'm happy with any GUI or command line tool that does the task.

Comment: Because your file is small enough, Excel works. But I'm curious which "proposed tool" you are talking about which can't handle your file. The one answer to the linked question mentions pyspread, and it easily handles many, many, many more columns than what you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft Excel](https://products.office.com/en-us/excel) will do this for you. It has a special paste option called 'Transpose':

[image]

It supports up to [16,384 columns](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwib09nl4sPbAhUEKVAKHfSLAUwQFggpMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.office.com%2Fen-us%2Farticle%2Fexcel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3&usg=AOvVaw3pcYajcbKorRAx-3DqAexZ) so this should work for your CSV file; just copy the content and Paste Transpose it in another workbook or sheet.

It's an online solution, but [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/) has the same option, and I expect other spreadsheet tools do too:

[image]